# Defining Surface gravity of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, vector-fields

For a Killing horizon associated with a Killing vector $K$, the surface gravity $\kappa$ can be computed by various methods, like
$$
\kappa^2 = - \frac{1}{2} \nabla^\mu K^\nu \nabla_\mu K_\nu \ .
$$
However Killing vectors multiplying a constant is still a Killing vector, and $c K$ is of course also null on the Killing horizon.

**I wonder what is the criteria to fix the constant $c$?** For Schwarzschild and Reissner-Nordstrom, I guess one can impose $|K|^2 \to -c^2$ at spacial infinity, but this doesn't seem to be the case for the Kerr black hole, since
$$
|\partial_t + \Omega_H \partial_\varphi|^2 \to +\infty  \ .
$$

Comment: Great question! Of course the answer is hidden in the difference.

Comment: However in a static, asymptotically free spacetime with time translation Killing vector $K=\partial_t$ one can set the normalisation 
$
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}K^2 =-1
$ 
and this fixes the surface gravity of any associated Killing horizon. In a stationary asymptotically flat spacetime the Killing horizon is associated with a linear combination of $K=\partial_t$ and $R=\partial_\phi$ and fixing the normalisation of $K$ fixes the linear combination and so also the surface gravity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Because the Killing vectors are defined to satisfy Killing's equation
$$ 2\nabla_{(a} K_{b)} = 0 \ , $$
a constant scaling is possible, and the value of $\kappa$ changes. You're also right that for the Schwarzschild metric (and for all static asymptotically flat spacetimes), one can fix the constant by demanding $K^a K_a|_{\infty} =-1$.

In general, there's no way to fix this constant. This is covered in a very nice discussion in the following paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1445   where they say

> This freedom corresponds to a gauge freedom to rescale the curve parameter along the integral curves of the Killing vector by a constant factor.

> In the general case, there is no natural way to fix the parametrization
> of this generator.

They then go on to discuss some other more general ways to define the surface gravity $\kappa$ in terms of different definitions of horizons/trapped surfaces. But the conclusion is really that, in general, there's no prescribed way of doing this (and depends on the context of the problem you're working with).